# Run docker-compose after reboot on RHEL 7

Tags: permissions, rhel, mount, docker, tmp

After [installing Docker CE](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-docker-ce-1) and [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose-on-linux-systems) on RHEL 7, I get an error trying to use it:

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
```

A quick Google of the error leads to a [one-liner solution](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1339#issuecomment-196971221):

```
sudo mount /tmp -o remount,exec
```

The problem is, each time the system reboots that command has the be run again.  I've considered making a Bash script run as root on bootup, but this seems hacky and hard to maintain.

**Is there a way to mount `/tmp` with the configuration Docker Compose needs?**

---

In case it's helpful, here is the output of `mount` and `/etc/fstab`:

```
$ mount | grep tmp
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=8119132k,nr_inodes=2029783,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02 on /tmp type ext3 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02 on /var/tmp type ext3 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run/user/16777223 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1626620k,mode=700,uid=16777223,gid=16777221)~
```

---

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Fri Oct 13 01:03:21 2017
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
UUID=9e305d5c-10d9-431a-ab40-8fc3a7a7bf81 /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol06 /home ext3 nodev 0 0
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02 /tmp ext3 nodev,nosuid,noexec 0 0
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol03 /var                    ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol04 /var/log                ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol05 /var/log/audit          ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-LogVol01 /local/apps             xfs     defaults        1 2
tmpfs       /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec 0 0
/tmp /var/tmp none bind 0 0
```

Comment: *Avoid putting answers in comments.*

Answer (score 0):

Your `/etc/fstab` is mounting the `/tmp` mount as `noexec` each time.

Replace that `noexec` option for the `/tmp` mount in `/etc/fstab` to be `exec` and reboot to see if that helps.